# Autonomous vehicle prices versus year

Tags: data-request

I would like to know where I can find a graph of the estimated price of fully autonomous driverless vehicles versus the year in which the vehicle is sold.

Does anyone know where I can find this data?

Answer (score 0):

There is some data in a 2017 academic paper, but I don't know if you'll have a yearly breakdown since the technology is considerably new.

[Cost-based analysis of autonomous mobility services](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0967070X17300811)

> Highlights
>
> - Comprehensive cost analysis of different types of autonomous vehicles.
> - Market predictions for electrified and/or autonomous vehicles.
> - Private vehicle ownership will likely endure the rise of such new technologies.
> - Mass transit likely confined to dense urban areas.
> - Service costs to be main cost factors of shared autonomous vehicles.

[image]

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tranpol.2017.09.005